# Swift : Alternative to .classForCoder()

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-runtime

Given the following code:

```
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AppDelegate.classForCoder()) {
        (definition) in

        definition.injectProperty("assembly")
    })
```

. . . it is necessary to use `.classForCoder()`, as `.class()` is struck out. This is certainly unintuitive compared to simply `.class()`. Is there an alternative that provides better readability?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To obtain a reference to the class Object, simply use 'ClassName.self'

Example:

```
return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AppDelegate.self) {
    (definition) in

    definition.injectProperty("assembly")
})
```